# Sending an email using smtplib via python

Tags: python, smtplib

I am using mailtrap as the smtp server to send emails. However, when I send an email, I receive an error. The log in credentials are correct and I changed the emails for privacy concerns. Note, I am running this on a pycom device directly connected to my laptop.

```
def sendEmail():
    sender = "Private Person <from@mail.com>"
    receiver = "A Test User <to@mail.com>"
    port = 2525
    smtp_server = "smtp.mailtrap.io"
    login = "username" # paste your login generated by Mailtrap
    password = "password" # paste your password generated by Mailtrap

    message = """
    Subject: Hi Mailtrap
    To: {receiver}
    From: {sender}

    This is a test e-mail message."""

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
            server.login(login, password)
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

        print('Sent')
    except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
        print('Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?')
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 147, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 114, in sendEmail
  File "<stdin>", line 106, in sendEmail
  File "/flash/lib/smtplib.py", line 84, in __init__
  File "/flash/lib/smtplib.py", line 110, in connect
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_SEC'
>
```

Line 106 refers to `server.login(login, password)` and line 114 is the line right after `print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))`

I have taken the snippet from the smptlib which is causing problems

```
def connect(self, host, port=0, source_address=None):
        if source_address:
            self.source_address = source_address

        if not port and (host.find(':') == host.rfind(':')):
            i = host.rfind(':')
            if i >= 0:
                host, port = host[:i], host[i + 1:]
                try:
                    port = int(port)
                except ValueError:
                    raise OSError("non numeric port")
        if not port:
            port = self.default_port
        if self.debuglevel > 0:
            print('connect:', (host, port), file=stderr)
        if self.tls:
            ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_SEC)
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(ss)
        else:
            self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
        try:
            self.sock.connect(socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][4])
        except:
            self.close()
        (code, msg) = self.getreply()
        if self.debuglevel > 0:
            print("connect:", msg, file=stderr)
        return (code, msg)
```

Specifically `ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_SEC)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: The name of your file does not happen to be `smtplib.py`, is it? if it is, change it

Comment: No, the name of my file is main.py. smtplib.py is a library in the lib folder. @DeepSpace